# Exclude/replace parts in different document versions

Tags: build-system

I have to publish a document in two versions:

1. Original full version
2. Chapters that have been published elsewhere must be excluded

My problem is related to version 2. Simply removing the appropriate chapters does not work since I have three restrictions:

1. I must keep the original page numbering (even though there will be numbering gaps)
2. The table of contents must be identical for both versions
3. In case of removed chapters I have to include a page which indicates that the chapter content is not there because it has been published elsewhere

To give an example, the following would be the “original full version”:

- Contents

  - Chapter 1…………1
  - Chapter 2…………28
  - Chapter 3…………86
- Chapter 1 (pp. 1-27)
- Chapter 2 (pp. 28-85)
- Chapter 3 (pp. 86-110)

Let’s assume “Chapter 2” has been published elsewhere. Hence, I have to remove pages 28-85. In addition I have to show a note on page 28 that the contents are not available because they have been published elsewhere. Hence, within the *.pdf-file page 86 follows immediately after page 28 (numbering gap). Examples for page 28 for both versions:

**Page 28: Original full version**:

[image: Original full version]

**Page 28: Reduced version (chapter 2 has been excluded)**:

[image: Version where chapter 2 has been excluded]

Using `\includeonly` and `\nofiles` allows me to remove chapters while keeping page numbering and the table of contents. However, I can't figure out how to replace the original "Chapter"-page with a reduced one as shown above.

A perfect solution would allow me to use some kind of switch to compile different versions.

Comment: Have your chapters that shall be excluded a substructure with `\section` etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\iffullversion
%\fullversiontrue

\newcommand{\extrainclude}[3]{%
  \iffullversion\else
    \expandafter\preto\csname cp@#1\endcsname{%
      \chapter{#2}
      The contents of this chapter has already appeared in \cite{#3}
      \cleardoublepage
    }
  \fi
  \include{#1}
}

\iffullversion\else
  \includeonly{chapter1,chapter3}
\fi

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\include{chapter1}

\extrainclude{chapter2}{This will not appear}{whatever}

\include{chapter3}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{whatever} I. Myself, My precious paper, 2015.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Instead of the bibliography entry you can modify the definition of `\extrainclude` to use differently the third argument where you can insert the full data.

If you uncomment the `\fullversiontrue` line, the whole document will be produced. Do it before commenting it, of course.

The trick is that if `chapter2.tex` is excluded from `\includeonly`, LaTeX will execute the macro `\csname cp@chapter2\endcsname`, to which we prepend the suitable action; then the standard behavior will follow, which is resetting the counters to their previous value.